# Crow branch pecking behaviour

Tags: zoology, ornithology, ethology, behaviour

I was walking through a small park when two crows started cawing at me, and followed me, flying from tree-to-tree as I walked. I speculate that this is a territorial or protective behaviour, but what I found different was the crows were violently pecking the branches nearby them. I have no memories coming to mind of seeing this behaviour beforehand. I speculate that this behaviour could be threat displays, but a quick search on Google did not reveal to me any authoritative studies on this phenomenon. I'd appreciate more information and sources.

---

This question has been added as a [casual observation on iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org/observations/111969279).

Comment: Anything like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQZj59-Kufc

Comment: @theforestecologist That is strikingly similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good question. This type of behavior -- pecking at a branch, wiping the side of the beak on a branch, pulling off twigs and dropping them, or knocking off pieces of bark -- is quite common among many corvid species, particularly when they are interrupted by something or someone that they might consider a threat. This includes not only potential predators but also potentially hostile conspecifics.

It is typically considered to be a form of [displacement behavior](http://www.animalbehavioronline.com/displacementbehavior.html). The concept of displacement behavior, from classical ethology, posits that when an animal experiences two conflicting drives to do two different things, it doesn't know which to do and does a third thing instead to dissipate the drive or anxiety. For branch-pecking in crows, see E.g Kilham and Waltermire 1990 Ch. 12.

**Referece:** Kilham, L., & Waltermire, J. (1990). *The American crow and the common raven*. Texas A&M University Press.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't resist. It is certainly amusing that the answer comes from you (with the name corvus and a crow for DP)

Comment: Indeed - as the resident corvid I felt somewhat obliged to answer this question.